# Migrating specific entries in table to UTC

Tags: sql, t-sql

so previously i migrated the dates in my db to UTC, however, some code changes didn't affect the new incoming data into my tables, so i'm stuck with local and UTC dates now.

I know which ones are incorrect, but i'm not sure how i would select them?

Previously i've used this query to migrate to UTC:

```
UPDATE [tblMeasureValue] SET TStamp = DATEADD(hour,-7,TStamp);
```

My table with dates looks like this:

```
   [PalletNumber]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
  ,[LastMeasurement]
  ,[CreatedDate]
```

how would i modify my new dates to UTC?

I've tried this query. but it updated all rows.

```
Update Pallets SET CreatedDate = DATEADD(hour, -7, (Select CreatedDate from Pallets Where PalletNumber = 63))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause should be with `update` statement :

```
update p
      set CreatedDate = DATEADD(hour, -7, CreatedDate)
from Pallets p 
where PalletNumber = 63;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remember previous update datetime then you can use that value in your update query:

```
Update Pallets 
SET CreatedDate = DATEADD(hour, -7, CreatedDate)
WHERE CreatedDate > @previousMigrateDateTime
```